# How do I include end-to-end tests across microservices into multiple continuous delivery pipelines?

Tags: automated-tests, microservices, end-to-end, continuous-delivery, ase

My team develops three microservices. The three work together to provide a business scenario. They communicate with REST and RabbitMQ. Looks like in [Toby Clemson's presentation on Microservice Testing](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/#testing-end-to-end-diagram).

Each microservice has its own continuous delivery pipeline. They are *delivery*, not *deployment* pipelines, meaning there is a manual release decision at the end.

**How do I include an end-to-end test for the *business scenario*, i.e. across all microservices, into the delivery pipelines?**

My team suggested this:

We add one *shared* end-to-end stage that deploys all three microservices and runs the end-to-end test on them. Each time one of the pipelines reaches this stage, it deploys and tests. A semaphore ensures the pipelines pass the stage one after the other. Failure stops all three pipelines.

[image: Shared end-to-end stage]

To me, this seems to sacrifice all the independence the microservice architecture wins in the first place:

- The end-to-end stage is a bottleneck. A fast pipeline could thwart slow pipelines because it reserves the end-to-end stage more often, making the others wait before they may run their tests.
- Failure in one pipeline would stop the other pipelines from delivering, also disabling them from shipping urgent bug fixes.
- The solution doesn't adapt to new business scenarios that need different combinations of microservices. We would either end up with a super-stage that wires all microservices, or each business scenario would require its own, new end-to-end stage.
- The end-to-end stage shows only a narrow result because it confirms only that one exact combination of microservice versions work together. If production contains different versions, it does not guarantee this will work as well.
- The stage is also in conflict with the manual release decision at the end: What if a build passed end-to-end but we decide to not release it to production? Production would then contain a different version of that microservice than end-to-end, causing warped results.

**So what's a better way to do this?**

Comment: Agree broadly. The problem I have with this proposal is that it creates a built-in assumption that you never want to release software unless a particular business case is satisfied. I would be tempted to place business case tests outside of the pipeline altogether and run periodically. Failures should then be raised as issues against the backlog of each service.

Comment: @Florian What solution did you come up with?

Comment: We implemented two different solutions, over time. The original idea sketched above was discarded. Instead we decided to give each pipeline an individual e2e test space. The pipeline would deploy its own service there. The other two pipelines would deploy their service at the very end. Thus, the e2e space always reflected "does my latest service increment work with the other two current production versions?" Over time, we found this still too cross-dependent. In later setups, we limit the pipelines to contract tests. And add a pipeline that regularly runs e2e tests in prod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short - Such an integration testing would not be part of the microservices development/deployement team and process, but a separate team having its own process. You can automate as much as possible in that team, but in the end you need a decision whether to release or not.

The longer explanation:

The Microservices architectural style was invented to help large organizations to manage large applications and avoiding overhead of communication and dependencies between teams. So if you want to follow this style, you should really have 3 independent teams - One for each service. Each of those teams would have complete responsibility over the whole life-cycle of their respective service. Now when you want to do end-to-end testing (often called integration testing) you would set up a 4th team that is responsible for those tests. And you would have one person being the responsible release manager who owns a staging/testing cluster and decides on when testing proves sufficiently to release a new version of a service into the wild. Your goal should be to decouple the teams as much as possible in terms of dependencies and release cycles of their services. If you want complete independence of the services teams you can also make the integration testing part of each team. Meaning you have testing/staging cluster for each team and a responsible testing/release manager role in each team.

Comment: If we wanted to pull the end-to-end test into the teams, this would mean that each microservice has its own end-to-end test stage. What would such a stage do? Would it deploy its own microservice plus the latest released versions of the other two microservices, then run an end-to-end test suite that's stored somewhere in an independent repository?

Comment: In such test stage I would deploy the production version of all services plus the one new service version that you want to test. Btw. in general the dependencies should be very limited with a Microservices approach and thus the risk of "integration"-failure low. That means you also have to think about if that investment is justified.

Comment: @OswinNoetzelmann This sounds a lot like I was expecting E2E tests in a microservice architecture with independent teams/deployments. Do you know anygood articles, books, talks or something about this topic? Or is this more a common knowledge?

Comment: "Each of those teams would have complete responsibility over the whole life-cycle of their respective service" ... "And you would have one person being the responsible release manager who owns a staging/testing cluster and decides on when testing proves sufficiently to release a new version of a service into the wild".

These two statements seem quite contradictory. If you've delegated end-to-end testing to a separate team, and they determine when to release, then the microservice teams not longer have complete responsibility.